# How does c++ determine whether an integer literal fit int type or not?

Tags: c++

I know the standard says if the integer literal does not fit the int, it tries unsigned int, and so forth, per section 2.14.2 Table 6 in the standard.

My question is: what's the criteria to determine it fits or not?

Why do both `std::is_signed<decltype(0xFFFFFFFF)>::value` `std::is_signed<decltype(0x80000000)>::value` gives `false`. Why don't they fit in int? `0x80000000` has the same bit representation as <s>`signed -1`</s> `signed -2147483648`.

Comment: By the `u` suffix at the literal.

Comment: *`0x80000000` has the same bit representation as `signed -1`.*  It does?  On what platform?

Comment: sorry, I meant -2147483648, which is minimum of signed int.

Comment: `0x80000000` is another way to write `2147483648`. Since your platform's `int` is probably 32 bit, `0x80000000` won't fit in an `int` since it's greater than the maximum a 32 bit `int` can represent, which is `2147483647` on your platform. `0xFFFFFFFF` is even bigger than that.

Comment: `0x7FFFFFFF` is a `signed int` and `0x80000000` is an `unsigned int`. If `int`s are 32 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to look at "bit representation" to check if the number fits or not.

Assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`, `int` can represent numbers from -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1 inclusive.

`0x80000000` is 2<sup>31</sup>, which is 1 larger than the maximum value.

Answer (score 3):

> what's the criteria to determine it fits or not?

Up to the platform and compiler. They define how big `int` is.

> Why do both `std::is_signed<decltype(0xFFFFFFFF)>::value` `std::is_signed<decltype(0x80000000)>::value` gives false.

Because in most platforms `0x80000000` and `0xFFFFFFFF` will be `unsigned int` because they do not fit in an `int`.

> Why don't they fit in int?

Because in most platforms `int` is 32-bit, two's complement, which means `0x7FFFFFFF` is the biggest `int`

Answer (score 3):

0xFFFFFFFF is hex for 4'294'967'295. On platforms where `sizeof(int) == 4`, the range of `int` is -2'147'483'648 to 2'147'483'647. As you can see 4'294'967'295 isn't in that range. Simple as that.